# How to access SERVER variable in Flask?

Tags: php, python, flask

like in PHP we can print the array $_server like this :

```
<?php 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SERVER);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

how can we access equivalent $_server variable of php in flask.

Comment: There's probably no *exact* equivalent. What information are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I want to display all the info which $_server contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **mod_wsgi**, over mod_python, your application is passed an environment variable such as:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
...
```

And the environment contains typical elements from $_SERVER in PHP

```
...
environ['REQUEST_URI'];
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't 1:1 with the contents of `$_SERVER`, but the `request.environ` object is immediately usable - i.e. works without needing mod_wsgi. Here's a minimal example:

```py
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    resp = [str(f"{f}: {request.environ[f]}") for f in request.environ]
    return "</br>".join(resp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True)
```

---

I had a small flask app running in docker-compose on a host that already had Apache and quite a bit of configuration. I was able to see all the hosts relevant info passed from the host.